# Need an extra Loop so if Cells in range 0 then do this, else if cells in range have data then continue

Tags: vba, excel

This script works but stops after the first then, I would like it to produce both outcomes so if blank cells Select Case `pf.Cells(i, 7).Value`, and then continue to check for cells with data and perform the required case.

At the moment it stops after either action.

```
Sub NewPortName03()

    Dim pf As Worksheet, pi As Worksheet, eq As Worksheet
    Dim Rws As Long, Rng As Range, c As Range, cr
    Dim s0 As String, s1 As String, s2 As String, s3 As String, s4 As String

    Set pf = Sheets("PAR Form")
    Set pi = Sheets("PAR_import")
    Set eq = Sheets("Equipment details")

    s0 = "CAT6A"
    s1 = "RJ45"
    s2 = "LC-LC"
    s3 = eq.Cells(4, 4).Value
    s4 = ""

    With pf
    Rws = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "P").End(xlUp).Row
    Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(2, "P"), .Cells(Rws, "P"))
    End With

    For Each c In Rng.Cells
    cr = c.Row

If c = s4 Then
  pi.Cells(cr + 48, 3).Value = pf.Cells(cr + 0, 26).Value

  ElseIf c = 1 Then

    For i = 2 To 34
  Select Case pf.Cells(i, 7).Value

  Case "CAT6A"
    pi.Cells(i + 48, 3).Value = "PCI-" + eq.Cells(4, 4).Value + "-" + Left(pf.Cells(i, 16), 7)

  Case "RJ45"
    pi.Cells(i + 48, 3).Value = "PCI-" + eq.Cells(4, 4).Value + "-" + Left(pf.Cells(i, 16), 7)

  Case "LC-LC"
      pi.Cells(i + 48, 3).Value = "PFI-" + eq.Cells(4, 4).Value + "-" + Left(pf.Cells(i, 16), 10) + ":" + pf.Cells(i, 40) + " to " + Left(pf.Cells(i, 17), 10) + ":" + pf.Cells(i, 42)

End Select
    Next i

End If
Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: Remark: you have a `Next c` at the end but no coresponding `For c`

Comment: It was to address the -  For Each c In Rng.Cells - vba would not let me end sub without it.

Comment: I've never put the variable name in the Next line when using for each, Just `next` should be enough.

Comment: I see that the string concatenations are build with `+`, It should be `&`.

Comment: Ahh Im going to be adding about 6 more for C's using similar variables this is just part 1 of the code,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tightened up you code somewhat and replaced the For Each with an index based For Next. The set of strings got stuffed into an array and Case criteria that resulted in the same outcome got stacked together.

```
Sub NewPortName03()

    Dim pf As Worksheet, pi As Worksheet, eq As Worksheet
    Dim Rws As Long, cr As Long
    Dim vSTRs As Variant

    Set pf = Sheets("PAR Form")
    Set pi = Sheets("PAR_import")
    Set eq = Sheets("Equipment details")

    vSTRs = Array("CAT6A", "RJ45", "LC-LC", eq.Cells(4, 4).Value2)

    With pf
        Rws = .Cells(Rows.Count, "P").End(xlUp).Row
        For cr = 2 To Rws
            If Not CBool(Len(.Cells(cr, "P").Value2)) Then
                pi.Cells(cr + 48, 3) = .Cells(cr + 0, 26).Value
            ElseIf .Cells(cr, "P").Value2 = 1 Then
                For i = 2 To 34
                    Select Case UCase(.Cells(i, 7).Value2)
                        Case vSTRs(0), vSTRs(1)
                            pi.Cells(i & 48, 3) = "PCI-" & vSTRs(3) & "-" & Left(.Cells(i, 16), 7)
                        Case vSTRs(2)
                            pi.Cells(i & 48, 3) = "PFI-" & vSTRs(3) & "-" & Left(.Cells(i, 16), 10) & ":" & .Cells(i, 40) & " to " & Left(.Cells(i, 17), 10) & ":" & .Cells(i, 42)
                    End Select
                Next i
            End If
        Next cr
    End With

End Sub
```

The one thing that still concerns me is that you are using `.End(xlUp)` to determine the extent of the row(s) in the **PAR Form** worksheet's column P. You are also looking for blank cells as you walk through the values in column P. Are there interspersed blank cells in column P or should you be basing the extents of the For Next loop on another column? In other words if column N goes to row 100 but column P only goes to row 75, your For Next loop currently only goes to row 75.